# What is the best way to show location in Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation, rails-geocoder, geokit

I'm building an app for a client.  The client want to be able to display street map with its location on the contact page.

I've never used maps in a web app before and I've been googling around.

there are so many options to use and I´m not sure which one to use.... this is just for displaying the streetmap, with a pin or something at the address, nothing too fancy.

should I use geokit-rails?

or rubygeocoder?

or Google Maps API?

or is there something else I can use?

what do you guys/girls recommend?

any suggestions would be great

thanks in advance
D

Comment: I prefer the most generic one 'Google Maps API' because if later you work on different framework (i.e. .Net), you'll find it easy to do the same integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use gem geocoder which I like. Just `gem install geocoder`. It supports geocoding and reverse geocoding, distance queries, rails 3-5. It is on github and website is [here](http://www.rubygeocoder.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try `gmaps4rails` gem.

It is simple and easy to intregrate in rails application.

Check the Docs [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails).